# Ideal development environment for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

I am embarking on the rewrite of a VB6 product in C# using Visual Studio 2010.

Would it be better to use Windows XP or Windows 7 for the development environment?

Comment: What does the Windows version have to do with that? Visual Studio runs on both, so what you use is a matter of preference.

Comment: What criteria would you use to define "better"? Wouldn't that make this a fairly subjective question?

Comment: If you don't subvert the security features of Windows 7 (like running your app or IDE as admin, or disabling UAC on your dev machine), then Windows 7 will allow you to become more [LUA-aware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) while porting your application.  It also (supposedly) makes better use of beefier computers.  Other than those things it should make little to no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're targeting Windows XP only, there is no reason to saddle yourself with an obsolete OS: you won't be able to develop for any of the new platform's features and there is a good chance you'll be unable to install many of the most recent OS components.

So get a Windows 7 system and setup a win XP VM for testing

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP has a lot less restrictions on what you can do, so for a straight out conversion project its probably easier. However, Windows 7 is becoming more prevalent (at least in my customer base. How about your customers?), and using it would give you the opportunity to do it "right" with regard to file locations, settings storage, user rights, among other things. The cost is more time, of course.

Also, if you are aiming to get your product MS certified, then having a Windows 7 certification is probably more meaningful.

So, in summary, your answer should be based on your goals for the application, and the needs and wants of your customers.

Answer (score 0):

.Net is designed as multi-platform, and theoretically doesn't depend from OS

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with windows 7 any day. Win xp is old and boring, there are no benefits from using it

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is far better than XP in EVERY way, don't let the nostalgic XP lovers fool you. :)